# Random password generator python

Tags: python, random, passwords, password-generator

When i run the following code and i open the file called **pwd.txt** it shows the same password in all the 100 lines

```
import string
from random import *
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8,16)))
with open('pwd.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(100):
        f.write(password + '\n')
```

Comment: That's because you are writing the same password 100 times. You need to generate new random ones within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You only generate *one* password, outside loop. Generate a new password each iteration instead:

```
with open('pwd.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(100):
        password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8,16)))
        f.write(password + '\n')
```

Expressions are not automatically re-evaluated when you write them to a file, you need to *explicitly* run the same expression again and again.

You could put it in a function if you like, but it bears repeating: your `password` string is not going to be recreated every time you write it to the file without explicitly creating a new string.